# third party semantic issues

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

I'm very new in react native mobile app development and having problem to run my app on ios simulator and iphone 7.

environment:
OS:10.12.6
xcode:8.3.3

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5

I did try multiple approaches from internet search but nothing is worked. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**BUILD FAILED**

[image]

The following build commands failed:

> CompileC
>
> /Users/fngo/dermo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/raw_logging.o
>
> /Users/fngo/dermo/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/raw_logging.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>
> CompileC
>
> /Users/fngo/dermo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/symbolize.o
>
> /Users/fngo/dermo/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/symbolize.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (2 failures)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dermo.app
>
> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>
> Failed to install the requested application
>
> An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>
> Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>
> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dermo.app/Info.plist
>
> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist